# Check if a JFileChooser has 1 or multiple files selected

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

How do I check if my `JFilechooser` has one file or multiple files selected?

Comment: A small suggestion - It is always better to read the javadocs. You get to know more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
if(files.length > 1) {
//More than one file selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid of me to not have thought if that xD Monday mornings :p

Comment: Glad it helped. @Junaid said, Javadoc is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the selection size:

```
getSelectedFiles().length > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method to fetch selected files

```
 File[] files = jfilechoser.getSelectedFiles();

int selectedFiles = files.length;
```